# React JSX В чём отличие "class name" от "cost name" по своему предназначению?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Изучаю React.

Например, что такое `class` в верстке-html, понимаю. Но что такое `class` в React js не пойму.
В чем разница между
`class name extends Component { render() { return ( ... ) }}` и
`const name = () => { return (...) }` ?

И момент. В первоисточнике вижу акцент на то, что `const name = () =>....` это анонимная функция.
Что такое функция и что такое анонимная функция понимаю. Если это функция, то что такое `class name extends Component {...`?

Синтаксис `const` и `class` понимаю. Если `class` замороченей `const`, для чего `class` если `const` проще.

те же словари `{key : 'value'}` и списки `[..., ..., ...]` можно ведь и в `const` тогда закладывать. Для чего `class`?

Comment: Кажется вам для начала JS надо подучить

Comment: Не спорю. на JS обратил внимание и года не прошло как. Просто переквалифицироваться хочу в веб-программисты

Куда там сунуться в JS, что упустил, можно ссылочку хоть? 
Тогда пойду помониторю class в js

Comment: Почитайте для начала книгу по JavaScript непосредственно, прежде чем приступать к чему-то более специализироаанному